# Extract year from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to extract the year from a random string?
For example "randomtext20221108randomtext"

The text before or after it's never the same, but the date format "20221108" it is.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Is the text before truly random (i.e. could it also have 8 numbers in a row)?

Comment: `patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', col)`?

Comment: Can the string contain other numbers that aren't the date?

Comment: @EdmCoff it's truly random

Comment: @Stu yes, the text "csvTable1" at the end

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky the output in the case is "2022". SSMS 2016

Comment: is the length of the random text  before year fixed or also random? And please edit the question to include relevant info, rather than answering in comments

Comment: If it's truly random, does that mean you need to check that it's a valid date as part of the search (to handle the case where the random text happens to have 8 numbers in a row so `SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',col),4)` isn't enough)? Or what is the exact process of ruling out the the initial text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query may help you,

```
DECLARE @yourText varchar(100) = 'randomtext20221108randomtext'
DECLARE @begin int = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @yourText)
DECLARE @end int = @begin + 7

SELECT SUBSTRING(@yourText, @begin, @end - @begin + 1)
```

and if you need only year, you can do,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('randomtext20221108randomtext', PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 'randomtext20221108randomtext') , 4)
```

Comment: This will not return correctly if it encounters four digits anywhere in random text. IE: "random1234text20221108aaa"

Comment: @NenadZivkovic OP didn't mention there are digits

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi OP mentioned "it's truly random".  And OP never specified characters only.  That includes 4 random numbers.

Comment: @Zorkolot But he has accepted the answer as the correct answer, and if he has any problem with it, he will inform again

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following example might work for you, makes the assumption dates are all this century

```
select s, Substring(s, p, 4) [Year]
from (
  values('kdfjgkj44kjf420221108dfkgjhdfiuh45rt'),('qwerty20210409'),('nodate 2345 here')
)t(s)
cross apply(values(NullIf(PatIndex('%2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9][1-9]%', s),0)))p(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #randomTexts (col1 nvarchar(max));

insert into #randomTexts values ('randomtext20221108randomtext');
insert into #randomTexts values ('2022asdasd20211108randomtext');
insert into #randomTexts values ('1234567820181108randomtext');
insert into #randomTexts values ('xxx20331332zzz20221108randomtext');

WITH CTE_Numbers AS 
(
    SELECT MAX(LEN(col1))-1 as n FROM #randomTexts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT n-1 FROM CTE_Numbers
    WHERE n>0
)
SELECT col1,CAST(SUBSTRING(col1,n,8) AS DATE) AS validDate, SUBSTRING(col1,n,4) AS year
FROM #randomTexts
CROSS JOIN CTE_Numbers
WHERE TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(col1,n,8) AS DATE) IS NOT NULL
AND n+8<= LEN(col1);
```